# How to share instance between decoratee and decorator in the context of ScopedLifestyle.Flowing

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, command, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I don't understand how to to share instance between decoratee and decorator by using a DI container.

The following example illustrates my problem. The `context` instance is shared between the `TransactionCommandDecorator` and the `Command` service.

```cs
var context = UowFactory.GetUnitOfWork();

var command = new TransactionCommandDecorator(
    context,
    new Command(context));
    
command.Execute(new CommandParams { });

context.dispose();
```

Basically I need to have a lot of commands that interact with the database and make some call to a repository. I want then to apply a transaction by making use of a decorator that wraps the command service.

The problem is that i don't know how to share the context between the decorator and the decoratee (like in the example) because i need to having a new `DbContext` instance for every execution of the command.

Do you explain how i can make this to work by using Simple Injector in the context of Scope flowing (`ScopedLifestyle.Flowing`).

This one possible example of implementation of decorator and decoratee

Command Example:

```cs
public Command(IUnitOfWork uow) => _uow = uow;

public DbResult Execute(CommandParams args)
{
    _uow.Repo1.Add(args.Item);
    _uow.Repo1.Add(args.Item2);
    _uow.Repo1.Remove(args.Item3);
}
```

Transactional Command decorator:

```cs
public class TransactionCommandDecorator : ICommand
{
    public TransactionCommandDecorator(IUnitOfWork uow, ICommand command)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _command = command;
    }

    public DbResult Execute(commandParams args)
    {
        try
        {
            var transaction = _uow.GetContext().Database.GetTransaction();
            var ret = _command.Execute(args);
            
            if (!ret.Success)
            {
                transaction.Discard();
                return;
            }
            
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            transaction.Discard();
        }
        finally
        {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IUnitOfWork` can be shared between classes with in the same `Scope`, by registering it as `Lifestyle.Scoped`, as shown in the following example:

```cs
container.Register<IUnitOfWork>(() => UowFactory.GetUnitOfWork(), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.Register<ICommand, Command>();
container.RegisterDecorator<ICommand, TransactionCommandDecorator>();
```

Usage (using ScopedLifestyle.Flowing):

```cs
using (var scope = new Scope(container))
{
    ICommand command = scope.GetInstance<ICommand>();

    command.Execute(new CommandParams { });
}
```

Usage (using ambient scoping):

```cs
using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
{
    ICommand command = container.GetInstance<ICommand>();

    command.Execute(new CommandParams { });
}
```

Comment: Thk @Steven, i begin to understand better the lifetime of classes with the container usage. i think that i need a big mind shifting on how to arrange the classes architecture that for now it's a little bit obscure to me sadly. 
So for what i have understand...every time a class hold a reference to IUnitOfWork it need to be wrapped by a ScopedCommandDecorator...it is correct?

Comment: @FedericoBorghesi it depends. In your WPF application views and view models can live for a long time, which would cause their dependencies to do as well. This might be problematic for dependencies such as `DbContext`. In that case, a good solution is to wrap the business operation in a decorator that applies scoping. But when you need decorators around many classes, it might be good idea to make your decorators generic, which you might already being doing.

Comment: yes i want exactly to do this to but in my case i have every concrete command that implement IDatabaseCommand<TResult,TParam>? 
How i cam make a generic decorator for that ? In my architecture i need to having a Decorator for each implementation of a particular IDatabaseCommand?

For Instance IDatabaseCommand<DataResult,Command1> has his decorator for scoped and IDatabaseCommand<DataResult,Command2> has his decorator too?
like [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64575662/decorator-for-creating-scope-with-scopedlifestyle-flowing-in-simple-injector)

Comment: In your previous question, you referred to the AOP section of the Simple Injector documentation. That section contains a ton of examples about generic decorators.

Comment: Very precious help thk again. 
I started to thinking now about your another reply about AOP in a previous post. Thk again and sorry about my sometime silly question but i try to study this between my normal work and my spare hour so sometime i miss something. I visit now the AOP section in the docs but it could be that the Documentation site it's down?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm. Readthedocs is down for me too.